# cannot import name 'normalization' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.layers'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use tensorflow_rankings, but cannot import it due to the above error. I am using tensorflow 2.8.0 and tensorflow_rankings 0.5.0, which seem to be the latest stable builds. They are what get automatically installed from

```
pip install tensorflow
pip install tensorflow_ranking
```

I am on Python 3.8.10, Windows 11.

The TF 2.8.0 docs show there is a Normalization layer in tf.keras.layers. The error seems to come from:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import normalization as keras_norm
```

in

```
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
```

Any advice?

Comment: don't use imports from tensorflow.python, import directly from tensorflow.keras.layers

Comment: It should be `Normalization`, with a capital N

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I did not import this manually. It is in the tensor flow source code

Comment: @Solvalou I tried changing the TF source code to capital N but it did not work.

Comment: We don't have the details, you only posted a line without context, also note that tensorflow and tensorflow_ranking are not the same library

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Yea, tfr needed to import the layer from tf. Seems a clean reinstall of everything fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my installation of TF was corrupted. A full uninstall and reinstall fixed it.